# Developing VS Code extension bundled with other extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

What happens when I develop a VS Code extension and want users to install it bundled with other extensions of my choice?

In which file of the extension project should I write it, and how?

Want to tell me where to write, or how.

Answer (score 1):

You can bundle extensions together in **Extension Packs**, set of extensions that will be installed together.

```
{
  "extensionPack": ["xdebug.php-debug", "zobo.php-intellisense"]
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest#extension-packs